# UIViewController handle orientation iOS 6.0 on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, ios6

In my application, I need to handle a different orientation for my `ViewControllers`.

1. `ViewController1` must support only landascape orientation.
2. `ViewController2` must support landscape + portrait orientation.

I enable, in Summury project, all orientations like this:

[image: Summary project orientation]

So, I insert this code in `ViewController1`:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

And I insert this code in `ViewController2` :

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

The problem is that `ViewController1` rotates also in portrait orientation (it should support only landscape orientation).

Any idea?

Thank you all very much!

Comment: [This link may help you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12651309/1059705)

Comment: I have already read this discussion, but it's not helpfull for me

Comment: It's a bit tricky. This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12755727/653513

Comment: Have you solved the issue? I have similar problems with rotations on ios6

Answer (score 1):

Is your viewController your rootViewController ?
If not, that may be your problem.

If your rootViewController is a UINavigationController, you should know that it not forward those messages to it's topViewController. So if this is your case, i suggest that you use a subclass of UINavigationController in which you override those new methods in order to forward to the topViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Before iOS 6 this works fine

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientatio n { if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)) return YES;

else return NO; }
```

But in iOS 6 is deprecated

Now you should specify the orientations that want and select a orientation for presentation

you should write

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations { return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape; }

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation { return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight; }
```

Hope it helps

Good Luck